# Android Volley - Unexpected response code 400

Tags: android, json

I am working on an android project where i have a registration screen , when i click on register button i am posting all the details to the server , here i am using volley library for networking operations.

I am testing the application with `Nexus 5 device(Android version 6)` and `YUREKA device(Android version 5.1)` the registration process works prefectly.
Now my problem is when i test the application with `HTC desire 501 (Android version 4.1.2)`, the registration process gives me `400` error.
So i debugged it to see and what i found is change in syntax of json

For `nexus 5` and `yureka` i am getting json as

```
[{"drv_dtoc":"2016-02-09 15:26:17",
  "drv_mobno":"1111111111",
  "drv_clientcode":"DEMO",
  "drv_name":"abc",
  "drv_imei":"12345678904242"}]
```

For htc desire 501 i am getting json as

```
["{drv_name=xyz, drv_clientcode=DEMO, drv_imei=456372940373809,  
   drv_mobno=2222222222, drv_dtoc=2016-02-09 T 15:17:25}"]
```

Can anybody tell me what to do ?

Comment: can you post the code how you creating json request

Comment: change first line to  `["containerKey" : {"drv_dtoc":"2016-02-09 15:26:17",`

Comment: @PunitSharma the registration process is working with HttpClient library , but not working with volley in htc desire 501